# how to save number of eye views of telegram in php

Tags: api, save, view, telegram

How Can I save the eye views of per post in telegram in php?
now I can save the post it self(telegram-cli) but i can't save the number of visits of a posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
updateChannelMessageViews#98a12b4b channel_id:int id:int views:int = Update;
```

When the number of channel views increases the server will send you the above update.

The `views` property above is your current number of channel views

You can modify your Telegram-cli to include a handler for `updateChannelMessageViews` message type.

Comment: updateChannelMessageViews#98a12b4b channel_id:int id:int views:int = Update;
how can I use above code in php? would you make a sample code? Thanks!

Comment: You need to modify your cli codes to capture the above message type.

Comment: Sorry I don't use that cli but what I think you need to do is modify your cli codes and try to capture this particular message type when it is sent by telegram: **updateChannelMessageViews**